# How to explore a JGraphX object (ie finding edges and nodes)?

Tags: java, jgraphx

I get the graph by an xml string, so first of all I transform it in an mxGraph object:

```
mxGraph newGraph = new mxGraph();
org.w3c.dom.Node node = mxXmlUtils.parseXml(xml);
mxCodec decoder = new mxCodec(node.getOwnerDocument());
decoder.decode(node.getFirstChild(),newGraph.getModel());
```

Now I'd like to do something like:

```
for Edge edge newGraph.getAllEdges()
     System.out.println(edge.src+" "+edge.dst);
```

However getallEdges return Objects and I can't find any Edge class...it seems strange to me...

Answer (score 1):

```
newGraph.clearSelection(); 
newGraph.selectAll();
Object[] cells = newGraph.getSelectionCells(); //here you have all cells
for (Object c : cells) {
 mxCell cell = (mxCell) c; //cast
 if (cell.isVertex()) { //isVertex
   //todo
 }else{ //is not a vertex, so u can get source and target 
   //todo
   cell.getChildCount(); //Returns the number of child cells. (edges)
   cell.getChildAt(x); //Returns the child at the specified index. (target)
 }
```

Att,